# How to discover unsatisfied declarative services references in OSGi programmatically

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

How can I reach the information that is available through the "ls" and "comp [id]" commands in the OSGi console programmatically so that I can log information about unsatisfied references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Equinox [org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService](http://felix.apache.org/apidocs/scr/1.0.8/org/apache/felix/scr/ScrService.html) serves a purpose similar to the SerivceComponentRuntime mentioned above, which I couldn't find in Eclipse Mars 2.

org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService is located in org.eclipse.equinox.ds bundle.

Sample reference definition:

```
 <reference 
    bind="setScrService" 
    cardinality="0..1" 
    interface="org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService" 
    name="ScrService" 
    policy="static"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the one I needed.
I am using the service from outside of the OSGi framework, so I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150855/using-service-component-runtime) to get it to work in stead of the sample reference you have provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all information via the OSGi service that is registered with the [ServiceComponentRuntime](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/runtime/ServiceComponentRuntime.html) interface.

Comment: Correct. This service is new in DS 1.3.